# PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, nginx

I know that this has been reported many times but I can't still fix the problem after following some tutorials.

I have already tried the following code under wp-settings.php as instructed at [wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) site:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

I also increased the memory_limit in my php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

But I'm wondering why it still complaining a value of 134217728 bytes. Since I already increased the value to 256MB, supposedly the error should return like:

```
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 268435456 Bytes Exhausted
```

I can verify by running phpinfo() that the memory_limit is already 256M after restarting php5-fpm and even nginx.

Can anybody please shade some light on this problem?

Comment: Yes. I have already restarted php5-fpm. In fact I can see that the value is already 256m and not 128m.

Answer (score -1):

The error is: that the allowed memory size of 256MB is *exhausted*. Your app needs more memory (**256MB is very very much for a website**), but why? You have to do some research, because it seems a deeper problem. It's good for you to check which plugin uses so much memory.

Install a plugin to check/monitor the performance en resources:

- P3 Plugin Performance Profiler
- Memory viewer
- Debug bar

So you can check the resources (cpu, memory, etc.) of your plugins. More detailed information: http://www.stumiller.me/how-to-monitor-and-reduce-wordpress-memory-usage-by-plugins/

Answer (score -1):

Your set of `memory_limit = 256M` is stil low. Try something bigger like `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` If 512M throws fatal error go or 1024, but keep in mind that it may not be the best thing to do.

Install xDebug with webgrind and profile your app.